# jEdit slow on Linux

Tags: linux, troubleshooting, java, jedit

[Jedit](http://www.jedit.org/) is a great text editor, and I love that it is truly cross-platform.  I usually use it on windows and just recently spent a long while working on some stuff on my linux box and noticed a large difference in performance.  Switching between buffers, in particular, takes much longer than on windows.

I'm using Ubuntu 8.10 and latest version of Java from Sun, tried using -xms/x from 128M to 2048M and it only seems to impact the time it takes to load the program.  I tried upgrading to the lastest jedit in the repos (4.3pre17) but that has not helped either.  I disabled all plugins (I use projectview, buffertabs, and a few others) but this did not change anything.

I don't know if this is a jedit-specific problem or a java issue in general; jedit is the only program I run in that way (invoking java on a .jar, etc)  Does anyone else run it and could recommend some tweaks to either to improve performance?

Answer (score 2):

> I'm using ... latest version of Java
>   from Sun

Did you install from the Sun website, or from the Ubuntu repository (sun-java6-jre)?

If you installed from the repo, you might still be using the default Java version instead, which can be rather slow.

Run:
`sudo update-alternatives --config java`

This will show you which versions are installed and which version is used by default.

If the Sun version is not selected, select it by doing:

`sudo update-java-alternatives --set java-6-sun`

Answer (score 1):

got the same problem with OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.6) (fedora-29.b16.fc11-i386)
Okay it's Fedora :-) but changing the JDK to SUN Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_16-b01) everything runs fine.

Using SUN's jdk will speed up things

Regards

Mischa

Answer (score 0):

Try going to "Utilities > Global Options > jEdit > Text Area" and disabling everything connected with anti aliasing. Usually that speeds it up a bit.

Comment: Of course those DirectDraw options only apply to running jEdit under Windows

Comment: Ugh, screwed up. That's what happens when you're in a hurry... Removed.